# Angular.js bug with safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I'm working on an app, that's client side is written in angular.js.

It works perfectly EVERYWHERE, even in safari ... until I reload.

When I reload in safari the page renders blank, but here's the kicker - when I open up developer tools to debug i cant duplicate.

Once I close dev tools and refresh - blank.

I hope this question doesn't get closed due to its vagueness ... Hopefully somebody has experienced this in the past.

If it helps; the app communicates with a RESTful api which is "housed" on a subdomain.

Comment: Could be a caching issue. In some dev tools you can force it to always get from the server. I've never used Safari dev tools, so I don't know if does that by default or something. Also, if you can't reproduce it when stepping through js code, it's often a race condition.

Comment: Is the api returning 304?

Comment: Its hard to say anything with any certainty - when I check the xhr request (with debugger) it shows a 200 response, not a 304 - but then again, it works with the debugger open, and doesn't without it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like safari simply ignores a 304 response and renders a blank body... I'm guessing that dnc253 and tasseKATT were right, in that the debug tools just disabled cache.

For some reason adding a fake meta header like `<meta name="304Fix" content="safari-fix">` fixed the problem ... I have 0 understanding of why.